# Switching dp and sp in an image/text to a percentage?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, image, text

When I add an image in a proper way using "dp" and when I add a text to my application in "sp," the application looks like A (the picture) .. but when I check the application in a smaller smartphone, it's a bit screwed up :) (as in B)
Is there away using a percent on a text/image to look like big and small smartphone the same? as in (C and D)?

[image: source: http: //tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2m4rjpd&s=8#.VJLGVMkm9dd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the purpose of dp & sp: the purpose is to keep image/text size at nearly the same *physical* size disregarding the pixel density/dimension of any particular device an application is running on. So of course their size wouldn't change depending on how large the screen is. For more info see [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

If you do want to have larger image/text for larger devices, put your larger image assets in `/drawable-<dpi>-sw600dp` and your image/text size definition in `/values-<dpi>-sw600dp`, where sw600dp is [Smallest-width Qualifier](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali).